# View no longer updates even on scope.$apply()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a very weird quirk where if I set an object property, the view stops updating with any changes made to that object, or even within the scope.

Here are my directives:

```
.directive('viewEditEntry', function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.on('click', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.item.editing = true;
          scope.item.editValue = angular.copy(scope.item);
        })
      })
    }
  }
})

.directive('viewSaveEditEntry', function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.on('click', function(){
        let self = this;
        scope.$apply(function(){
          Object.assign(scope.item, scope.item.editValue);

          scope.item.saving = true; //If commented out, no issues
          setItemInDB(scope.item);
        });

        function setItemInDB(item){
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){
            //Testing Code
            console.log('success'); //Runs
            scope.$apply(function(){
              console.log('success 2'); //Does not run
              item.editing = false;
              item.saving = false;            
            })          
          }).withFailureHandler(self.failure).client_EditTransaction(item);

        };

        self.success = function(response){
          console.log('success')
          scope.$apply(function(){
            item.editing = false;
            item.saving = false;            
          })
        }

        self.failure = function(response){
          console.log('success')
          scope.$apply(function(){
            item.editing = false;
            item.saving = false; 
          })
        }            

      })
    }
  }
})
```

The `item` is an element in an ng-repeat.

Under `setItemInDB()` any code inside of the `scope.$apply()` does not run. Any changes made to the object do not appear in the view eve after a digest cycle.

However, if I comment out the `scope.item.saving = true` line. There are no issues, changes reflect on the object, and the `scope.$apply()` behaves like expected.

Why is this happening? I have nearly identical code in another small app that does not seem to display these issues.

**AngualrJS** 1.5.8